# Websocket with Express and TS

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, sockets, websocket

I've had a question about socket.io with Typescript and ExpressJS, below is my code for open connection with my app using websockets (index.ts).

```
export const webSocket = new socketio.Server(server, { cors: { origin: "http://localhost:5000" }});
webSocket.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("Socket connected!")
  socket.emit('connection', null);

  socket.on("sendMessage", (payload) => {
    await saveMessage(payload);
  })
});
```

Is there any way to to `socket` across whole project and not only with this one file (index.ts) where i initialize connection with socketio? Right now I can use `webSocket` const across whole project because I', exporting this variable and I can e.q. use `webSocket.emi(...)`, But is there any chance to do this same with `socket` variable from `on` callback function?

Thanks for any help!